# Molodensky Transform with PROJ

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geodesy, geodetic

I'm trying to transform some geodetic coordinates from the Ellipsoid (Hayford) to WGS84. I downloaded QGIS and I'm trying to use PROJ, with the OSGeo4W shell.  I'm trying first to run the example given in the documentation. [Example](https://proj.org/operations/transformations/molodensky.html?highlight=transformation)

`proj +proj=molodensky +a=6378160 +rf=298.25 +da=-23 +df=-8.120449e-8  +dx=-134 +dy=-48 +dz=149 +abridged` but I get the follow error get the error:

`<proj>: can't initialize operations that produce angular output coordinates program abnormally terminated`

Also, why are the parameters `+a`(semi-major axis) and `+rf` needed and what does `+rf` stands for?

Comment: `+rf` stands for "reverse flattening". flattening:1/298.25, reverse flattening: 298.25.

Answer (score 1):

Molodensky is a datum transformation, but you are using the `proj` application, which is used to projections.

You can perform datum transformations with `cct` application instead (https://proj.org/apps/cct.html#description):

```
cct +proj=molodensky +a=6378160 +rf=298.25 +da=-23 +df=-8.120449e-8  +dx=-134 +dy=-48 +dz=149 +abridged
0 0 0
 -0.0004311898    0.0013475059     -111.0000           inf
```

`+a` and `+rf` parameters define the source ellipsoid and `+da`, `+df`, `+dx`, `+dy`, `+dz` parameters define the transformation.

In the example, the transformation is using South American 1969 ellipsoid as source, but I don't know the target ellipsoid and datum for the transformation used.

I hope you know what parameters to use, the same that you know that this type of transformation is what you want to do.